# Неверная кодировка писем

Tags: кодировка, email, php

На моем сайте есть обработчик формы вот с таким кодом:

```
$username = @ trim ($_POST['username']);
$email = @ trim ($_POST['email']);
$message = @ trim ($_POST['message']);

if($username == NULL or $email == NULL or $message == NULL)
{
  echo 'Вы заполнили не все поля. Пожалуйста вернитесь назад и заполните форму еще раз.';
}
else
{
mail("admin@my-site.ru",
      "Message from www.my-site.ru",
      "$message \n\n Name: $username \n The sender's e-mail: $email");
echo "<div style='background:seashell;width:80%;margin:3em auto;text-align:center;border:1px solid grey;'>";
echo "Спасибо!<br /> Ответ придет на указанный Вами e-mail-адрес $email в ближайшее время.";
echo "<br /><a href='http://www.my-site.ru'>Вернуться на сайт.</a></div>";
}
```

---

Проблема в том, что в письме приходящем на ящик, будь-то mail.ru или rambler.ru, неправильно отображается кириллица. Doctype страницы с формой utf-8.
Я сохранял обработчик и в utf-8 и в windows-1251. Все равно вместо русских букв кракозябры. Погуглил, нашел вот такой код для конвертации кодировок, но ничего в нем, честно говоря, не понял, так как в php не очень хорошо разбираюсь.

```
<?php

function send_mime_mail($name_from, // имя отправителя
                        $email_from, // email отправителя
                        $name_to, // имя получателя
                        $email_to, // email получателя
                        $data_charset, // кодировка переданных данных
                        $send_charset, // кодировка письма
                        $subject, // тема письма
                        $body // текст письма
                        ) {
  $to = mime_header_encode($name_to, $data_charset, $send_charset)
                 . ' <' . $email_to . '>';
  $subject = mime_header_encode($subject, $data_charset, $send_charset);
  $from =  mime_header_encode($name_from, $data_charset, $send_charset)
                     .' <' . $email_from . '>';
  if($data_charset != $send_charset) {
    $body = iconv($data_charset, $send_charset, $body);
  }
  $headers = "From: $from\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=$send_charset\r\n";

  return mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
}

function mime_header_encode($str, $data_charset, $send_charset) {
  if($data_charset != $send_charset) {
    $str = iconv($data_charset, $send_charset, $str);
  }
  return '=?' . $send_charset . '?B?' . base64_encode($str) . '?=';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$bound="raZdeLitel_9988";
$subj="Сабж";
$headers="From: \"Ми\" <mail@майл.рф>\n";
$headers.="To: \n";
$headers.="Subject: $subj\n";
$headers.="Mime-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers.="Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$bound\"\n";
$body="--$bound\n";
$body.="Content-type: text/html; charset=\"windows-1251\"\n";
$body.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";

$body.="
  <br /><br />Текст<br />";
$body.="\n\n--$bound\n";
mail("mymail@mail.ru", $subj, $body, $headers);
```

Контент должен быть конвертирован в windows-1251 в данном примере. Данная конструкция позволяет так же посылать аттачи, их достаточно разделить разделителем $bound в теле ($body) и указать заголовки к файлу.

Answer (score 2):

В заголовке письма явно укажите кодировку письма и его тип (html/text, обычно). И будет Вам Щазтье!

Comment: Это получается так что-ли:
mail("admin@my-site.ru",
      "type='text/html' Message from www.my-site.ru",
      "$message \n\n Name: $username \n The sender's e-mail: $email");

Comment: как ниже написано =)

Answer (score 2):

```
$rem_mail = '[e-mail]';
mail($rem_mail, "Проверка", "Это тестовое письмо", "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

Решение проблемы с крокозябрами, абракадаброй, неверной кодировкой, некорректной кодировкой писем отправленных на [mail.ru](http://mail.ru) php-функцией mail() в кодировке utf-8:

В качестве темы письма указать: =?utf-8?B?". base64_encode("Тема"). "?=

Т.е. должно получиться:

```
$to = "somemail@mail.ru";
$subject="=?utf-8?B?". base64_encode("Тема письма"). "?=";
$header="From: mysite.ru"; 
$header.="\nContent-type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"";
$message = "Текст письма";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
```