# Функция mail() в php

Tags: php

Только открыл сайт, сейчас его редактирую, проблема в том, не знаю, как сделать, чтобы ссылка появилась, а то она у меня отображается в виде текста.

А вообще мне понравилась подтверждение почты на этом сайте с картинкой. =) Как так сделать?

```
$addres = $mail;
$subgect = "подтвердить регестрацию draw-art.ru";
$message = "здраствуйте " .$create_login."\n Для завершения регистрации, проследуйте по ссылке: <a href='draw-art.ru/activate.php?code=".$code."'>перейти</a>";
         mail ($addres,$subgect,$message,"Content-type:text/plain; Charset=windows-1251\r\n");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Тут думаю найдете ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/25529/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#25558)

То есть, правильные заголовки все вопросы решат. text/html.

Comment: Я сделал, как вы сказали: изменил на `Content-type:text/plain`, но по ссылке перейти не могу, почему? Внизу браузера даже ссылка не высвечивается и картинка не передалась. В той теме коды есть, но описания нету, не очень понятно, что и для чего это нужно.

Comment: ссылку полную отправляйте.. http://draw-art.ru/...

Answer (score 0):

Нужно письмо формировать в html формате, а не в текстовом

Comment: А ссылка разве не html формат?))

Comment: Ссылка - да, html, а письмо в целом - текст. Потому теги не обрабатываются.